# How do I use Microsoft LiveChat LX-3000?

Tags: sound, webcam, xfce

Work gave me a LifeChat LX-3000 headset.  I plugged it in, and now Mixer shows it in a bunch of options.[image]

But it doesn't matter which one I select, I can't get sound to go out to the device, not even in Skype which is what I want it for.  What am I missing?

```
:~> cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

Using XFCE4.

Comment: Try it with `pavucontrol` installed. German: http://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?topic=4538.0

Comment: Done. Also found an english source. pavucontrol is not that difficult ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install [`pavucontrol`](http://thelinuxexperiment.com/tag/pavucontrol/). You should be able to get it working with that.

Found an [english source](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=101073.0) along with the [german](http://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?topic=4538.0) one I posted in comment.

Comment: Amazing, I just had to install it and click the checkmarks beside the LX-3000 in both output and input tabs, and I can make Skype calls.  Too bad the Linux version of the Skype client sucks.

Comment: You are welcome to create a new better and improved skype but I bet it's due to patents and other stupid restrictions ...

Comment: I think it has a lot more to do with the fact that Microsoft bought Skype.  The Linux client hasn't updated since then.

Comment: (+1) I want to add, that in my case (laptop, ubuntu 12.04 with xfce), I had to additionally turn off the builtin-Audio in PulseAudio -> Configuration to make skype collaborate.

Comment: Also make sure the mute button on the head set is not clicked! My pair of headset seems to have been muted when taking them out from the packaging!

If the red led lamp on the control (on the headset wire) is on, then it is muted. Click the mute button again (the one under the volume control buttons), so that the lamp turns off, to close the muting.

Answer (score 2):

so I had the problem of not hearing the sound through my Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000 which was connected to my laptop with sysop Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I tried these two easy steps and it worked out for me.

1. Installing pavucontrol by running the following command line in the Terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol padevchooser
   ```
2. go to system setting,
3. find item SOUND (in my laptop, sound was between printers and wacom tablet),
4. in the OUTPUT section, switch the Speakers from `Built-in-Audio` to `Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000`

Comment: On 1/11/18 LinuxMint couldn't find padevchooser.
apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol 
was sufficient. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering how to deal with this device when Jack and Cadence manage your sound, you can go to Cadence -> Configure -> Driver tab -> ALSA driver and select the right input and output:

[image]

You will need to rested Jack afterwards (in Cadence, click "Stop" and then "Start"), and make sure that your PulseAudio bridge is running (Jack Bridges -> PulseAudio -> Start).

Tested with:

- Ubuntu 18.04-derivative (64 bits)
- Cadence 2:0.9.0+git20180427v5
- pulseaudio-module-jack 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2
- jackd2 2:1.9.12+git20190321~zz~bionic1